# Looking for library to convert PDF to PCL

Tags: .net, pdf, printer-control-language, pdf-conversion

I'm looking for a library to convert PDF to PCL.  I also need to put additional instructions (probably @PJL COMMENT statements)  We're trying to convert pdfs for input into an automated faxing system.

I would like to be able to call this from a .net environment either by directly referencing a .net assembly, using COM, or P/Invoke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GhostScript might convert PDF to PCL (see www.ghostscript.com)

This would be via running a the commandline app or using pInvoke on the dll.